# How do I add a comment (#) in front of a line after a key word search match

Tags: shell, sed, aix

I have a crontab file contains many database names  such as

```
10 06 1 * *   script  DEVE_DB1 
10 06 1 * *   script  TEST_DB1 
10 06 1 * *   script  PROD_DB1 
....
```

I would like to add a comment, `#` , in front of `TEST_DB1` in the entire file so that my cron job will not run all `TEST_DB1` jobs.

I found the following script on this site, 
`sed -e '/TEST_DB1/, s/^/#/'`

but I get an error:

`sed: 0602-404 Function /TEST_DB1/, s/^/## / cannot be parsed.`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Lose the comma (the space is optional):

```
sed -e '/TEST_DB1/s/^/#/'
```

Given the start `/TEST_DB1/,`, `sed` would be expecting to find the second address in a range, such as a number, `$`, or another pattern.  The `s` doesn't fit any of these constructs, hence the error.

Comment: So to do it all at once: sed -e '/TEST_DB1/s/^/#/' < crontab-file > crontab-file.new ; mv crontab-file.new crontab-file

Comment: On AIX, yes; if you had GNU `sed`, you could use `sed -i -e '/TEST_DB1/s/^/#/' crontab-file` to do it in situ, but that is (almost certainly) not available as an option with AIX `sed`.

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thank you guys.  The answer was so fast.

Comment: @Chimera, you probably want `sed '...' < file > new && mv new file` -- use && instead of semicolon. Then, the original file won't get overwritten if the sed cmd fails.